# Keyboard Fn always active

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I've enabled by mistake the <kbd>Fn</kbd> like <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and now if I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, I get `/` char instead of `=` because I have a notebook with <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

So, the only way to disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> function is to press it. How can I disable it to return to it's original state?

Answer (score 1):

It was the `Bl Num / Bl Scor` key

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen on 12.04.

What happened was I connected a USB keyboard and on that keyboard, I pressed the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key. Once I disconnected the USB keyboard, it was like the function key was always selected when I used the keyboard on my laptop.

To fix, I connected the USB keyboard again and hit <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> and that reverted it.